# Filtering out rows based on closest date

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a file with thousands of records that need to be filtered.
A sample of the data is provided below.  These are test scores for a school.  The source is a flat file (csv)
The goal would be to filter records and only output only one record closest to 01/15/2016 12:00 for each ID number
Is this possible, if so how would you go about doing so with SSIS or SSDT?  I'm not sure if this would be done using a conditional split, derived column, etc. and which command(s) to use to get the closest row to the desired date and time.  Thanks so much in advance!!!

sample of data from csv source file

`ID, FNAME, LNAME, DATE, SCORE1, SCORE2, SCORE3
1, JOHN, DOE, 12/11/2015 7:44, 100, 99, 98
1, JOHN, DOE, 12/29/2015 11:45, 99, 100, 96
1, JOHN, DOE, 1/10/2016 11:46, 98, 97, 97
1, JOHN, DOE, 1/20/2016 8:47, 97, 98, 99
1, JOHN, DOE, 3/20/2016 11:48, 96, 96, 100
2, JANE, DOE, 12/12/2015 11:44, 100, 99, 98
2, JANE, DOE, 12/28/2015 11:45, 99, 100, 96
2, JANE, DOE, 1/9/2016 11:46, 98, 97, 97
2, JANE, DOE, 1/23/2016 9:47, 97, 98, 99
2, JANE, DOE, 3/8/2016 8:48, 96, 96, 100
3, CHRIS, DOE, 2/8/2016 8:00, 100, 100, 100`

The desired results which will be written to a csv flat file destination would be
`ID, FNAME, LNAME, DATE, SCORE1, SCORE2, SCORE3
1, JOHN, DOE, 01/10/2016 11:46, 98, 97, 97
2, JANE, DOE, 01/9/2016 11:46, 98, 97, 97
3, CHRIS, DOE, 2/8/2016 8:00, 100, 100, 100`

Answer (score 3):

I would do this by importing the entire .csv to a staging table, and then running a stored procedure that uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the desired row for each ID, and copies only that row to the final destination table.

This will have better performance than trying to handle this in an SSIS data flow.

Example

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    FNAME, 
    LNAME, 
    DATE, 
    SCORE1, 
    SCORE2, 
    SCORE3 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) as RN
    FROM
        YourStagingTable
) a
WHERE 
   a.rn = 1
```

Comment: Pretty much what I'd do - possibly use an OPENQUERY/OPENROWSET if the SQL Server has direct access to the file, which is unlikely. But most cases, it would involve pulling the file into a table of sorts and running something pretty much like what you have above. If you need to join to other data, I'd consider an OUTER APPLY for that query to still get the results in a set-based manner.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use SSIS to achieve the desired result.  We are working with csv source files not a SQL database.  It has to pull the row with the date closest to a specified date, can't use row number because the number of rows always differs.

Comment: So, you are importing .csv files, and using ssis to export the rows to new .csv files?    There is no database involved at any point in the process?